# grep to fetch whole line

Tags: text-processing, text

I have a file like:

```
  Chr1    Cufflinks       exon    7136    7944    .       +       .       gene_id "XLOC_000001"; transcript_id "TCONS_00000003"; exon_number "5"; gene_name "LOC_Os01g01010"; oId "TCONS_00000003"; nearest_ref "LOC_Os01g01010.2"; class_code "="; tss_id "TSS1"; p_id "P2";
  Chr1    Cufflinks       exon    8028    8150    .       +       .       gene_id "XLOC_000001"; transcript_id "TCONS_00000003"; exon_number "6"; gene_name "LOC_Os01g01010"; oId "TCONS_00000003"; nearest_ref "LOC_Os01g01010.2"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS1"; p_id "P2";
```

I want to fetch the whole line, where ever there is a "u" in a line

The output should be like:

```
  Chr1    Cufflinks       exon    8028    8150    .       +       .       gene_id "XLOC_000001"; transcript_id "TCONS_00000003"; exon_number "6"; gene_name "LOC_Os01g01010"; oId "TCONS_00000003"; nearest_ref "LOC_Os01g01010.2"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS1"; p_id "P2";
```

I tried `grep -o "u" a >b`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
awk '$22 ~ /\"u\";/' file
```

If there is variable number of fields as mentioned in comments and `class_code` precedes required field this could be helpful:

```
awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) { if ($i ~ /class_code/) { if ($(i+1) ~ /\"u\";/) { print $0; break; } } } }' file
```

Comment: sorry its not working

Comment: I did not see ';'

Comment: The `;` won't make a difference. I'm guessing that the OP's input file won't always have `"u"` in the 22nd field.

Comment: @terdon I think it works both ways, but really don't know what is the problem.

Comment: It does work both ways for the example input. However, the GFF format which the OP is using can have a variable number of fields in `$NF`.  There's no guarantee that `$22` will be what you want (there's also no way for you to know this from the OP's question, of course).

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk` you can match column 22 using

```
awk '$22=="\"u\";"' a
```

Answer (score 2):

```
grep "\"u\";" a >b
```

will also do the job.

Answer (score 2):

In the simplest case, where you just want any line that contains `"u"`, you can do

```
grep '"u"' a > b
```

If you want to make sure it only matches in the description field of your gff file (assuming this is a [properly formatted](http://www.sanger.ac.uk/resources/software/gff/spec.html#t_2) gff file with tab-separated fields), you can do:

```
awk -F"\t" '$NF~/"u"/' a > b
```

Finally, if you are only interested in cases where the `"u"` is in the 7th sub field field of the attribute's field, you can use:

```
awk -F";" '$7~/"u"/' a > b
```

Answer (score 1):

Or `grep` for `class_code "u"`:

```
grep 'class_code "u"' input
```

Comment: -1 I think, that's a bad idea.

Comment: Why do you think this is a bad idea?

Comment: That what you're looking for, this could change tomorrow. It's just not a good style.

Comment: Whatever you're looking for can change tomorrow. That's also the case for "u".

Comment: That's right. But not for `class_code`. OP said where ever there is a `"u"` in a line and not "where ever there is a `class_code "u"` in a line"

Comment: It's just not clear what the OP really wants. Does the OP mean `u`, `"u"`, `"u";` or `""u""`? So you should downvote the other answers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22693/discussion-between-a-b-and-flohimself).